# Python, pandas: how to remove greater than sign

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following example DataFrame

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'A':['1', '<2', '3']})
```

I would like to convert the column A from string to integer. In the case of '<2', I'd like to simply take off '<' sign and put 1 (the closest integer less than 2) in the second row. What's the most efficient way to do that? This is just a example. The actual data that I'm working on has hundreds of thousands of rows. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Series.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1', '<2', '3']})
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:])-1 if x.startswith('<') else int(x))
print(df.dtypes)
# A    int64
# dtype: object
```

yields

```
print(df)
   A
0  1
1  1
2  3

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **applymap** on the DataFrame and remove the "<" character if it appears in the string:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('<',''))
```

Here is the output:

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other ways of doing this which may be helpful on the go-forward!

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'A':['1', '<2', '3']})
```

Outputs

```
df.A.str.strip('<').astype(int)
Out[1]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

And this way would be helpful if you were trying to remove a character in the middle of your number (e.g. if you had a comma or something).

```
df = DataFrame({'A':['1', '1,002', '3']})
df.A.str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

Outputs

```
Out[11]:
0       1
1    1002
2       3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: int(re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', x)))
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```